# Cómo Añadir un #id a un botón en Vue.js de forma dinámica

Tags: javascript, html, css3, vue.js

Quiero aplicar un estilo en concreto a un `<li>` cuando se clicka en su botón correspondiente.

Para ello Tengo un array (`items`) y dependiendo de cuantos haya se generan tantos `<li>` de forma "dinámica":

```js
 <ul class="item-list-ul">
        <li v-for="i in items" :key="i.id">{{ i }}
          <b-button @click="strikeItem(i)" variant="outline-dark">Hecho!</b-button>
          <b-button @click="deleteItem(i)"  variant="warning">Borrar</b-button>
        </li>
      </ul>
      
 items: ["cuatro","items","hay","aqui"]
```

En el ejemplo que puesto en el código se generarán entonces cuatro `<li>`

Lo que quiero hacer es asignar un Id diferente a cada li dependiendo de la cantidad de items que haya (es decir, la `i`), para así si se clicka el botón "HECHO", que la funcion `strikeItem(i)`aplique un estilo a ese id ese exacto `(id="i")` y así sólo se cambie el estilo de ese li en concreto .

He visto que con clases se puede hacer: `:class=""`El problema es que la `i` es un número si o si y no se pueden declarar clases numeros en CSS, pero si ids:

```css
// CSS si lo permite:
#3{
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
// CSS no lo permite:
.3{
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Si no no me importaría usar clases.

Comment: Y por qué no le pones un carácter no numérico como prefijo?

Comment: Por qué el i lo genera el bucle. ¿Podria hacer el bucle pero con letras?

Comment: Por supuesto ```:key="`id${i.id}`"```

Comment: Cierto, y como puedo añadirlo de id al <li>? De la misma forma omitiendo el ":key"?

Comment: Sí. ```:id="..."```. Perdona por la brevedad pero no tengo tiempo ahora para publicar una respuesta.

Comment: Entiendo,gracias igualmente. Si sabes porque puede ser por qué me sale "idundefined" en cada <li> despues de escribirle :id="`id${i.id}`" en cada <li>? Es decir la directiva :id ha funcionado bien pero parece que el ${i.id} no lo ha metido bien porque sale undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias cosas que te pueden ser útiles.

Lo primero de todo es no complicarnos.
Si realmente necesitas usar una clase y teniendo en cuenta que CSS no permite<sup>1</sup> crear clases que empiecen por un número, vamos a añadirle un prefijo delante, por ejemplo `class`.

De esta forma nuestra clases CSS se llamarán de la siguiente forma: class0, class1, ..., classN.

Para bindear una clase con el formato que queremos dentro en un bucle `v-for` podemos hacer lo siguiente:

```
<li v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i" :class="{[`class${i}`]: true}">
  {{ item }}
  ...
</li>
```

La importante está ocurriendo aquí:

```
{[`class${i}`]: true}
```

Estamos usando un [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings) para formar el nombre de la clase, que estará compuesto por el prefijo class concatenado a la posición del elemento.

Como tus items no tienen un atributo id, he optado por utilizar el índice que provee Vue en el `v-for`.

Tienes más información del binding de clases y estilos en Vue [aquí](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html).

Ejemplo funcionando [[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mq85wjbp/1/)]

---

1. [Parece que hay alguna forma de crear clases con números](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37998273/3866134)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div v-bind:id="'btn'+i.id"></div>
```

Esto es todo lo que debes hacer.
Solo busca una propiedad que generes con el v-for que no se repita y agregala como id y listo